# Fixing bad spelling suggestions

Tags: macos, spellcheck

Is there any way in macOS to fix or improve spelling suggestions that are very obviously wrong, like this one?

[image]

Is there some setting somewhere that can be tweaked to make spellcheck less dumb/aggressive?

Comment: What app are you using.  Iget the exct opposite on my machine. i'll spell "Lets" and it'll recommnd "Let's".

Comment: I wish :\ It's even worse with your/you're or there/their/they're. Actually, mine has no opinion whatsoever on lets/let's, but I didn't do anything to 'fix' it. I'm on Mojave, UK English.

Comment: Whether it's incorrect depends on usage, as "let's go" is a correct shortening of the exhortation "let us go." Have you reviewed Finder > Help > Spelling > Check Spelling and Grammar? It provides methods to delete words and suggested spellings from the built-in dictionary.